# I can not compile with Haxe

Tags: haxe

I just set up Haxe with OpenFL and Neko and created a project. I'm trying to compile it and to compile a default project or a small program from a tutorial which has no errors and I can not compile anything. I receive the following messages:

> Running command: haxe Export/linux64/neko/release/haxe/release.hxml
> /usr/share/haxe/std/neko/_std/EReg.hx:33: characters 11-61 : Unsupported escaped char 's' and it finish compilation with "aborted".

Someone told me to downgrade neko to 2.0 or to upgrade Haxe, however the versions that installs from official repositories for Ubuntu following the tutorials from Haxe website are Haxe 3.2.1. and Neko 2.1.0 which seems to be incompatible. After searching I found a list of compatibility in the Haxe GitHub website that seems to be the reason of the issue:

> Version compatibility
>
> Haxe  -   neko
>
> 2.*     - 1.*
>
> 3.0.0 -   2.0.0
>
> 3.1.3 -   2.0.0
>
> 3.2.0 -   2.0.0
>
> 3.3.0 -   2.1.0

I found the solution, I wanted to avoid building from source but there is no other way to install compatible versions of Haxe and Neko. After building version 3.4.0 of Haxe I can compile without problems. I hope this info is useful.

Comment: You don't need to build from source to install compatible versions. You can check the required versions by opening the projects xml file in a text editor. Infos on how to install a specific version is explained on the official docs: for the "haxelib install" command: https://lib.haxe.org/documentation/using-haxelib/

Comment: I tend to find the Kha approach of embedded in Kode or git submodules means that you get less setup problems. Perhaps OpenFL should explore similar approaches to boost it's stability.
http://kha.tech/getstarted